# Flutter Checkbox value storage in Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, checkbox

My setup is simple: i am making a landing page using Flutter web: users input their email add and tick a Checkbox if say they are over 18.
For the life of me I can not find a way to store both email add and the boolean value of the checkbox in the SAME RECORD in Firebase?
the UI and Firebase all setup and working ok, here the code snippets:

```
`child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _emailController,
                      // The validator receives the text that the user has entered.
                      validator: (val) => !EmailValidator.validate(val!, true)
                          ? 'Please enter a valid email.'
                          : null,
                      onSaved: (email2save) => this.email2save = email2save,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(
                            Icons.email_outlined,
                            color: Color(0xFF0000CC),
                          ),
                          hintText: "Please enter your email",
                          border: InputBorder.none),
                    ),
.......
Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('Please tick here'),
                      MyStatefulWidget(),
                      Text(' if over 18'),
                    ],
                  ),
.......
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool isChecked = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color getColor(Set<MaterialState> states) {
      const Set<MaterialState> interactiveStates = <MaterialState>{
        MaterialState.pressed,
        MaterialState.hovered,
        MaterialState.focused,
      };
      if (states.any(interactiveStates.contains)) {
        return Color(0xFF0000CC);
      }
      return Colors.black;
    }

    return Checkbox(
      checkColor: Colors.white,
      fillColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(getColor),
      value: isChecked,
      onChanged: (bool? value) {
        setState(() {
          isChecked = value!;
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't see any Firebase in the code you've provided above but it is actually pretty easy to add two or even many things at once to Cloud Firestore:

```
 var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection(collection_name)
            .doc(document_name);
 collection
                    .set({
                      'email': 'email2save',
                      'check': 'isChecked'
                    })
```

You can do this anywhere in your class and it will work like magic.

Comment: Thank you friend for your super quick reply :) I have collection name but no document_name? do I setup that up on the console?

Comment: If you don't have any specified document name then it will take anything random to create one so it is entirely optional to add

Comment: thank you ... you are a star! I will give it go now and report back.

Comment: sure and please upvote and mark it as an answer if it satisfies you

Comment: Great worked ok with some modifications.